# Lua Get values of text file lines

Tags: file, text, lua, line

In Lua I need to read the value of these, it's like an ini text file,
the names could be on any line.

```
color=3776EB
vsize=200
hsize=400
vpos=20
hpos=40
tittle=TEST
```

Comment: Do they need to be formatted like that? Perhaps you could use a .json file and the lua-cjson package from LuaRocks.

Comment: They are existing read only txt files eg. mixwnd_vis=0
prefs_x=371
prefs_y=182
prefspage=139
wnd_state=0
wnd_x=66
wnd_y=158
wnd_w=1854
wnd_h=765
transport_x=345
transport_y=160
transport_w=1057
transport_h=130
mixwnd_max=0
mixwnd_x=167
mixwnd_y=312
mixwnd_w=1602
mixwnd_h=529
mixwnd_dock=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
vars = {}
for line in io.lines("file.txt") do 
  var, val = line:match('^([^=]+)=(.*)')
  vars[var] = val
end
```

Then you have `vars.color`, `vars.hpos`, etc